# Error in sql query when using contains in aggregate expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, contains

Query:

```
    SELECT
        c,

        COUNT
        (   WHEN a='11' AND contains(b,'aa') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
        ) as total
    from x
group by c
```

Error:

> Full-text predicates cannot appear in an aggregate expression. Place
>   the aggregate expression in a subquery.

I am using contains because, it uses the index when searching in text, also the query is like that only, so i have to put it in aggregate expression only.... please suggest..

Comment: Why do you think you need COUNT anyway?

Comment: yes because in my original query i have group by clause...

Comment: So add the full query and expected results. Don't give partial information, especially when SQL Server only allows CONTAINS in a WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT total = COUNT(
    CASE WHEN a = '11' 
          AND CONTAINS(b, 'aa') THEN 1 
    END)
FROM x
```

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINS can appear only in a WHERE clause

```
SELECT
    c,
    COUNT(ContainsResult) AS total
FROM
    (    
    SELECT
        c, CASE WHEN a='11' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS ContainsResult
    from
        x
    WHERE
        contains(b,'aa')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c, NULL
    from
        x
    WHERE
        NOT contains(b,'aa')
    ) X1
GROUP BY 
    c
```